# I want to select a single and current div within div's and change it's background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this html content and I want to change the color of the current div when hover the mouse in it using jquery.

> CSS

```
.content{
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class="content">
        First
</div>
<div class="content">
        Second
</div>
<div class="content">
        Third
</div>
```

I was tried with this code but it wasn't work.

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color = $(".content").css("background-color");
    $(".content").hover(function () {
        $(".content").closest().css("background-color", "#F9FAF4");
    }, function () {
         $(this).closest().css("background-color", color);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just remove the closest() you code is fine.  Also use `$(this)` inside hover function instead of `$('.content')`

Comment: You don't need JavaScript here, you can accomplish this with CSS alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten to script to something as simple as:

```
  $(".content").hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("backGround");
  });
```

with some css:

```
.backGround {
    background-color: #F9FAF4;
}
```

[**Here is an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5mjkvjt7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In any event handler, you can rich the current object that triggers the event by `$(this).` So, it should work if you just change `$(".content").closest()` to `$(this)` and `$(this).closest()` to `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color = $(".content").css("background-color");
    $(".content").hover(function () {
       $(this).css("background-color", "#F9FAF4");
    }, function () {
       $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Lgd1sba4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var color = $(".content").css("background-color");
    $(".content").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#F9FAF4");
    }, function () {
         $(this).css("background-color", color);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)` to select the currently hovered item, like so:

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mt5nnr88/)